# Change button-design while pressing it

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm making a jungle timer for League of Legends, where I will make buttons you can click or you can start by a hotkey.

The button will be a picture of the specific jungle camp, and when the press/start it, it will start a timer, which will count down to when the jungle camp spawns again. When you press this button, it will change the design of the button to make the picture blurry and add a timer above it, that you can see.

My question is how do you change the design of the button, when you press it, like I explained?

*Keep in mind that I am very new to programming, and that this is one of my first programs.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the visual designer, look at the button's properties.  Any property can be referenced in the code with:

```
ControlName.PropertyName = value
```

eg.

```
JungleButton.Image = My.Resources.BlurryJungle
```

Embedded resources, such as images, can be added in the project's properties.

As for the progress timer, I'd suggest adding a separate control above the button, or utilise the button's Paint method and paint a couple of rectangles on the button to make a small progress bar.

Comment: How would you make that progress timer? Like what control would you use?

Comment: Two controls: a Timer and a ProgressBar.  Set the Timer to trigger in one second intervals.  The ProgressBar has the properties Value, Minimum and Maximum.  Set Maximum to the number of seconds the camp takes to respawn.  Increment Value once every time the Timer triggers.